# Load WPF UserControl dynamically

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dynamic-usercontrols

I have an abstract base class `aComponent` and sub-classes `CriteriaList`, `Question`, etc.

For each sub-class I have two corresponding `UserControl`s which have names like `ueCriteriaList`, `ubCriteriaList`, `ueQuestion`, `ubQuestion`, etc. (`ue` stands short for "`UserControl` with input elements", and `ub` for "`UserControl` with buttons".)

The `DataContext` is the "ControllerClass" with a property with `my_aComponent` as the getter for the actual `aComponent` instance. When the `aComponent` instance changes (for example to an instance of `CriteriaList`), I want to load the corresponding UserControls (in this case ueCriteriaList and ubCriteriaList).

I have two converters `ueControlConverter` and `ubControlConverter` which take the class name (e.g. `CriteriaList`) and return a `UserControl` instance (in this case, `ueCriteriaList`).

```
Public Class ueControlConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object,
                            culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object
                           Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim aComp As aComponent = value
        Dim assemblyKlassenname As String = aComp.GetType.ToString
        Dim assemblyName As String = Left(assemblyKlassenname,
                                          assemblyKlassenname.IndexOf(".") + 1)
        Dim klassenName As String = Right(assemblyKlassenname,
                                          assemblyKlassenname.IndexOf(".") - 1)
        Dim t As Type = Type.GetType(assemblyName & "ue" & klassenName)
        Dim o As UserControl = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
        o.DataContext = value
        Return o
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object,
                                culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object
                    Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

In XAML I have two `ContentControl`s which bind `Content="{Binding Path=my_aComponent, Converter={StaticResource _ueControlConverter}` and `Content="{Binding Path=my_aComponent, Converter={StaticResource _ubControlConverter}`. The right `UserControl`s are shown but without binding to `my_aComponent`.

What can I do?

Comment: Tip: .NET is better than VB6! `Dim split As String = assemblyKlassenname.Split({"."c}, 2)` `Dim assemblyKlassenname As String = split(0)` `Dim klassenName As String = split(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to also provide the **DataContext** property through binding for your **ContentControl** objects.

Comment: How can I get it in the Converter and use it there?

Comment: Hi @Potecaru Tudor, thanks for the answer. In my Converter I can see that the generated UserControl has the DataContext Null. This doesn't change after my "o.DataContext = value". How can I connect the generated UserControl-Object with my DataContext???

Comment: Hi @minitech, thanks for your edit - did you get my thanks when I write @minitech? I am new here and have to learn how formatting will work. And sorry for my English - I am from Germany. And respect, you seem to be very clever when you are invited to be an editor.

Comment: This problem is solved. In my test-class I overlooked that there isn't a property but only a public variable for the ObservableCollection. The Converter is functioning.